# how to set time 24h for jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I used jquery library TimePicker let customers choose the time.
http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/
and now I want it only displays the time in 24 hours starting from 0 am and ends at 23:59:59. anyone know how to handle it?

Comment: `'timeFormat': 'H:i:s'`?

Comment: But I don't think it supports steps in seconds...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pu8Lwben/1/

Comment: but if so then diverge too small. I just wanted to finish in time slots only.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you meant.... are you looking for time to be selected in seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has option for that, please read the document.

you need;

```
     $('#testpick').timepicker({ 'show2400': true });
```

Comment: I've moved on .... but when dc 24h format added to the SQL server, it k get that value is 23:59:59 .... it just get it. it k understand 24h by 23:59:59